# Adding a UICollectionViewController as a child UIView crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add a custom `UICollectionViewController` in a child `UIView` and it crashes my app. Is there something wrong with my code or how my `CustomCollectionViewController` is implemented?

```
@IBOutlet weak var childView: UIView!
let myCollectionView = CustomCollectionViewController()



//inside viewDidLoad
self.addChildViewController(self.myCollectionView)
self.myCollectionView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.myCollectionView.view.frame = self.childView.bounds<--crashes after executing this line
self.childView.addSubview(self.myCollectionView.view)
self.myCollectionView.delegate = self
```

[image: error]

Comment: Do you get an error reported when it crashes?

Comment: @Ollie It crashes and stops at my app delegate with "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: Is there a related error message as well? If not can you post the stack trace then we can see what is being called when the error occurs. I've just implemented your code in a demo project and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It's not something silly like your childView isn't hooked up to the storyboard is it?

Comment: Two questions: is the childView loaded and displayed before that part? does it work if you add the collectionView to the main view instead?

Comment: @Ollie I'm using a .xib file for my view controller and hooked up my childView to it. It crashes as soon as I set the frame of myCollectionView.

Comment: I see two issues here: #1 `didMoveToParentViewController` should be called after the child view controller moved to `DidAppear` state. You call it while the child is still in `DidDisappear` state. #2 You lay out the child in `viewDidLoad`. Layout should happen in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late, but initialize your `CollectionViewController` with a layout parameter.

Instead of:

```swift
let myCollectionView = CustomCollectionViewController()
```

use:

```swift
let myCollectionView = CustomCollectionViewController.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

That worked for me.